# Concatenate python string from list entries

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Lets say that I have a list of strings that I would like to jam together into a single string separated by underscores. I know I can do this using a loop, but python does a lot of things without loops. Is there something in python that already has this functionality? For example I have:

```
string_list = ['Hello', 'there', 'how', 'are', 'you?']
```

and I want to make a single string like:

```
'Hello_there_how_are_you?'
```

What I have tried:

```
mystr = ''    
mystr.join(string_list+'_')
```

But this gives a "TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list". I know its something simple like this, but its not immediately obvious.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You use the *joining character* to join the list:

```
string_list = ['Hello', 'there', 'how', 'are', 'you?']
'_'.join(string_list)
```

Demo:

```
>>> string_list = ['Hello', 'there', 'how', 'are', 'you?']
>>> '_'.join(string_list)
'Hello_there_how_are_you?'
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it I used:

```
mystr+'_'.join(string_list)
'Hello_there_how_are_you?'
```

I wanted to use the join function from the string, not the list. Seems obvious now.

Comment: You don't need to use `mystr` at all here; it is just an empty string.